Saving a merged layer changes attribute table columns to Asian characters
When I merge layers the temporary attribute table looks fine, with the expected column headings. However after I save the temporary layer, either by making permanent or by exporting features the column headings are in Asian characters except for the first column which is called Actions.
I have supplied the same layer files to merge and save to a colleague and this is not happening.
Also this has only just started happening in the last day for me. I have tried quitting QGIS and restarting.
I am using QGIS 3.28.2

What kind of dataset are you attempting to export?  If a shapefile what kind of encoding did you use to save the results?  You can right click on the layer and in Source change the encoding the project will use.  UTF-8 is the default.

Yes! They were shapefiles and the Encoding was set to UTF16-BigEndian, I've never looked at the Encoding before so I'm not sure when it happened but I must have changed it at some point, it's the next one on the list. Thank you for your help.
